# Loading ggtern package

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I’m having troubles loading the ggtern package. I believe it's installed correctly, but when I load it, I get this error:

```
> library(ggtern)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggtern’:

.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for ‘ggtern’, details:

call: modify_list(vals, list(…, … = NULL))

error: could not find function “modify_list”
```

My R version is quite recent (3.5.3), so I don't think it's an update problem. Do you have any idea what the problem would be?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, but you may wish to check / update your version of ggplot2. As far as I know, `modify_list` is an internal function from there. On GH, it was mentioned in a commit in Nov 2018, & eventually included in subsequent release versions. Other users have reported similar issue as yours over at [ggtern.com](http://www.ggtern.com/) in recent months.

Comment: it was more simple than what I thought. Indeed, I just needed to update ggplot2 even if on CRAN ggtern is listed as working for the version I had. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from AEBilgrau [Importing Error](https://github.com/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/39) actually works out my ggtern problem. I restart my r to get a clean session, and then run `install.packages("ggtern", type = "source")`. After running this installation, my error is gone.